# How to compose a query string when one of query string is URL that contains its query string in PHP?

Tags: php, url, get, query-string

In PHP, I would like to create a GET request by composing a query string. One of the query string key-value is like **url=http://www.example.com/a.php?id=xyz&name=def**, the rest of query string is like regular key-value pair.

However, when I compose them, the url will impact the whole GET request. For example, I have regular key-value pairs like **site=uts&user=zzz**, I will end up with getting the GET request like below

```
http://domain?url=http://www.example.com/a.php?id=xyz&name=def&site=uts&user=zzz
```

This is totally wrong. How can I pass url value in this GET request and avoid this situation?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.http-build-query.php takes care of all the necessary escaping for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, you will want to use urlencode.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

For example:

```
$url = 'http://domain?url='.urlencode('http://www.example.com/a.php?id=xyz&name=def').'&site=uts&user=zzz';
```

will produce:

```
http://domain?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fa.php%3Fid%3Dxyz%26name%3Ddef&site=uts&user=zz
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) and [urldecode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)